# How can I get the Operations Link Field back?

Tags: 8, views

I have a custom entity created in code which displays list in collection route. I decided to use a view to show this collection.

1. I created a new view of type 'Product' (Views shows my custom entity)
2. I added the fields I need to display
3. then searched for Operations Links (to add the edit, delete menu)

but it wasn't showing. I can confirm I've used this before in a view of custom entities.

Wat magic do I need to do here?

Answer (score 0):

I had deleted the "list_builder" handler from my custom entity's annotations - thinking I didn't need a list builder since I was using a Views handler. Well, turns out that was the problem. The "Operations" link in views came back after I reinserted the list builder handler in my custom entity.